# Se busca adjetivo: Fuera de lugar

Tags: adjetivos, solicitud-de-término

Necesito un adjetivo que reemplace a *desidioso* en "cuerpo desidioso". Algo parecido a la expresión "en Babia".

Es de los agradecimientos de un trabajo, la frase es:

> Igualmente quiero dar las gracias a mis amigos, por sacarme de casa y evitar la momificación de mi **cuerpo desidioso** durante la realización de este proyecto.

Pero *desidioso* tiene una connotación un poco negativa, como "sin ganas" o algo así.

Comment: ¿Podrías poner algún ejemplo del uso que quieres hacer del adjetivo en una frase concreta?

Comment: Tal vez "negligente" o "descuidado", pero coincido con @fedorqui en que necesitamos más información. Cuando más detalles tu pregunta mejor podremos responderla.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pese a que se trata de un documento formal como un trabajo, utilizas un estilo cordial y divertido propio de la sección de agradecimientos. Esto rebaja la formalidad, a la vez que apela al uso de palabras un poco "raras" para mantener el chiste en un estilo sobrio.

Por ello, se me ocurren distintas posibilidades:

> evitar la momificación de mi cuerpo **abúlico/negligente/apático** durante la realización de este proyecto.
>
> [**abulia**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=0DYwS2u)
>   1. f. Pasividad, desinterés, falta de voluntad.
>
> [**negliglente**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=QMAWQ4m)
>   1. adj. descuidado. U. t. c. s.
>   2. adj. Falto de aplicación. U. t. c. s.
>
> [**apatía**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=36mhKPA)
>   1. f. Impasibilidad del ánimo.
>   2. f. Dejadez, indolencia, falta de vigor o energía.

O incluso mencionaría **zángano** en tanto en cuanto vives a cuerpo de rey.

Answer (score 0):

Procrastinador. Inactivo. Inane.

Comment: Hola I. I. Dobón y bienvenido a [spanish.se]. Las palabras que sugieres puede que sean una buena solución; sin embargo, es bueno saber que para que la respuesta sea útil se recomienda añadir referencias, ejemplos, comentarios que sustenten lo que sugieres. Anímate a [edit]ar tu publicación.

Answer (score 0):

Cuerpo desanimado, desmotivado, perezoso.

Comment: Hola Inma y bienvenida a [spanish.se]. Las palabras que sugieres puede que sean una buena solución; sin embargo, es bueno saber que para que la respuesta sea útil se recomienda añadir referencias, ejemplos, comentarios que sustenten lo que sugieres. Anímate a [edit]ar tu publicación.